# How to get python os.environ parameters from cgi script?

Tags: python, cgi, environment-variables, rdkit

When I use

```
os.environ.keys()
```

in command line I get different environment variables than in cgi script. Is there a way to get python enviroment variables through cgi script?

Using

```
subprocess.Popen
```

I don't get the same parameters.

Can you help me please?

EDITED:

For example in command line my environment parameters are

```
['rvm_version', 'rvm_path', 'LESSOPEN', 'escape_flag', 'SSH_CLIENT', 
'LOGNAME', 'USER', 'HOME', 'PATH', 'RDBASE', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH', 'LANG',           
'TERM', 'SHELL', '_first', 'SHLVL', '__array_start', 'G_BROKEN_FILENAMES', 
'HISTSIZE', 'LISISTOOLS_PATH', 'GEM_PATH', 'rvm_bin_path', 'rvm_prefix', 
'PYTHONPATH', 'IRBRC', 'AUTODOCK_PATH', 'MY_RUBY_HOME', 'BOOST', '_', 
 '_second', 'SSH_CONNECTION', 'RUBY_VERSION', 'GRANATUM_LICENSE_FILE',      
 'OLDPWD', 'HOSTNAME', 'HISTCONTROL', 'PWD', 'SSH_TTY', 'MAIL', 'LS_COLORS', 
 'GEM_HOME', 'MGLTOOLS']
```

but from my cgi-script are:

```
['HTTP_COOKIE', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 'SCRIPT_NAME', 'SERVER_SIGNATURE', 
'REQUEST_METHOD', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL', 'QUERY_STRING', 'PATH', 'DUMP_FILE', 
'HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT', 'HTTP_CONNECTION', 'HTTP_REFERER', 
'SERVER_NAME', 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'SERVER_PORT', 'SERVER_ADDR', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT', 
'SCRIPT_FILENAME', 'SERVER_ADMIN', 'HTTP_HOST', 'REQUEST_URI', 'HTTP_ACCEPT',         
'GATEWAY_INTERFACE', 'REMOTE_PORT', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE',     
'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']
```

I want the first set of environment variables (command line) through cgi-script.

When I import in cgi script

```
from rdkit import Chem
```

I get the error

```
 /home/galaxy/working/RDKit/rdkit/Chem/__init__.py in ()
16  
17 """
18 from rdkit import rdBase
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: libRDGeneral.so.1: cannot open shared object 
file: No such file or directory 
  args = ('libRDGeneral.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or 
         directory',) 
  message = 'libRDGeneral.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file 
         or directory'
```

but in command line I get no error.

**PYTHONPATH** contains

*'/home/galaxy/working:/home/galaxy/working/RDKit:/home/galaxy/working/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.4/MGLToolsPckgs:/home/galaxy/working/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.4/MGLToolsPckgs'*

I update sys.path using

```
 sys.path.append('/home/galaxy/working')
 sys.path.append('/home/galaxy/working/RDKit')
 sys.path.append('/home/galaxy/working/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.4/
 MGLToolsPckgs')
 sys.path.append('/home/galaxy/working/mgltools_x86_64Linux2_1.5.4/      
 MGLToolsPckgs')
```

Comment: Your command line environment and the environment the CGI run in are different.  what info are you trying to glean via the environment?

Comment: You get different variables and values in each environment simply because they are different environments...

Comment: Is there a way to get the command line environment variables through cgi script?

Comment: What does your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable look like? Where is `rdkit` imported from?

Comment: I added it at the end of my question.

Comment: Add it to `sys.path` before importing (see my answer again).

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the situation: `os.environ` merely gives you the values of the process environment, which is provided by the operating system. Your CGI script runs under Apache, so it has a different environment from the same script when you run it from the commandline. (For example, `USER` will necessarily be different).

In short, what you're asking for doesn't exist. You *are* getting the python environment variables, they're just not what you expect. Please explain what you're trying to *accomplish*, i.e., *why* you're trying to get at these environment values. I could tell you how to set up your CGI script so that its environment matches your commandline environment, but who knows if that's what you need?

**Edit:** So your goal is to import a module. You can change the module import path dynamically by appending directories to `sys.path` (a list). Try explicitly adding the location of `rdkit`. You don't need the environment.

Comment: I know that, but I can't import a module in python cgi-script because these variables are different and apache can't find the module even though I added the paths in sys.path.

Comment: Keep talking. Explain what you're trying to import and why/how it fails. Put it in your question, that's the question you need to be asking.

Comment: Thank you. Please see my question again.

Comment: I added the location of rdkit, but the problem exists.

Comment: Let me look at my crystal ball... nope, nothing. You'll have to solve your problem yourself or provide more information.

Comment: But focus on `sys.path`, that's where the action is. Did you enter the right folder, in the correct format? Does CGI have read access to it? Use your python script to test these things (`print os.listdir(sys.path[-1])`, or whatever)

Comment: Except from PYTHONPATH values, do you think I should add more paths?

Comment: Add the path that contains `rdkit`.

Comment: Please check my question at the end.

Comment: The appending looks legit, but __where is `rdkit`__? You only need to add that one directory. From the commandline script, `print rdkit.__file__`

Comment: The result is **/home/galaxy/working/RDKit/rdkit/__init__.pyc** Will I append this path?

Comment: Well, rdkit seems to be in `/home/galaxy/working/RDKit`, and you're adding that. So I don't know what else is going wrong, sorry. I'd look at the other things I suggested (read access etc.). Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do

```
subprocess.Popen([cmd],env={'my':'environment','vars':4, ...})
```

and force a specific set of environmental variables

Comment: Yes I know that, but I want the values of pythons' envrironment variables